# Fillable PDF to HTML

Tags: javascript, vb.net, parsing, pdf

Is there any way to create simple fillable `embed`ed PDFs that allows me to extract the text via JS or ASP?

Now I know there are some libraries like `iTextSharp`, `pdf2html` etc. but I have found that these are just either overly complex or insufficient for my needs.

The scenario is this, I am trying to `embed` a tax document which the client may fill out, upon saving the document, the fields are then extracted into an object. As of now I have converted the `PDF` to `SVG` with `inkscape` but this still feels a bit bloated.

I just want to iterate through each field and store it accordingly.

Here's an example of one of the documents:

http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/E/pbg/tf/t4/t4flat-fill-13b.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the ways is to employ [FDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format#Forms_Data_Format_.28FDF.29) or [XFDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format#XML_Forms_Data_Format_.28XFDF.29) submits.

Basically, browser displays the PDF, user fills it and clicks a submit button. PDF viewer sends information about filled fields to specified URL.

You can choose format of the submit while creating the PDF.

Following is from the [XML Forms Data Format Specification](https://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/xml/XFDF_Spec_3.0.pdf)

> FDF is a simplified version of PDF. PDF and FDF represent information
>   with a key/value pair, also referred to  as an entry. This example
>   shows the T and V keys with values enclosed in parentheses:
>
> ```
> /T(Street)/V(345 Park Ave.)
> ```
>
> XFDF, on the other hand, represents an entry with an XML
>   element/content or attribute/value pair, as  shown in the correspond
>   XFDF:
>
> ```
> <field name="Street"> 
>     <value>345 Park Ave.</value> 
> </field>
> ```

Please make sure that not all PDF viewers might be able to submit forms data.

Comment: **EDIT** What would the form submission look like? I can't seem to find it anywhere

Comment: Please have a look here: http://www.gnupdf.org/Forms_Data_Format and here: http://answers.acrobatusers.com/Example-FDF-XFDF-file-q5362.aspx

Comment: Thanks again, the documentation was everything that I needed